# Python urllib2 read return different results for a ftp request, why?

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I ran into some werid behavior, these two functions echo different sizes always. The first one echoes certain and right result, while the second one
echoes random wrong results, is there anyone who knows why?  I am using Python 2.7.10.

```
import urllib2

url = 'ftp://ftp.ripe.net/pub/stats/ripencc/delegated-ripencc-extended-latest'

def one():
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    data = response.read()
    print len(data)

def two():
    print len(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

one()
two()
```

Comment: What happen if you change the call order? `two()` then `one()`

Comment: Might be a timing issue, spamming a server might cause it to throttle you. Have you investigated the data returned from the server?

Comment: just indices: from urlopen doc:
One caveat: the read() method, if the size argument is omitted or negative, may not read until the end of the data stream; there is no good way to determine that the entire stream from a socket has been read in the general case.

Comment: @falsetru order doesn't matter here, you can test it.

Comment: I think the problem is that the response object is closed in `two` before the whole response has been read as there is no direct reference to it. `len(''.join(iter(urllib2.urlopen(url).read, '')))` shows the same behaviour even if it is explicitly reading until the end of the stream.

Comment: One interesting thing is two gives a different count at times.

Comment: As noted by @poko, `read()` on a socket does not mean *read until end of file* but rather *read at least one byte and read as much data as is currently available*. The amount of data you get is essentially as much as is currently in the socket buffer (or received in the first chuck). It is actually surprising that the first read *seems* to consistently return all data.